# Calculate expense based on Start time and End time in lists

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a visitor list with start-time and end-time and I need to assign expense based on visitor arrival and exit.

For Example:

1. If start-time is at 7:30 AM and end-time 10:00 AM then expense against this visitor is 80 Rs.
2. If start-time is at 10:00 AM and end-time 12:00 PM then expense against this visitor is 400 Rs.
3. If start-time is at 7:30 AM and end-time 12:00 PM then expense against this visitor is 80+400=480 Rs, and so on.

Is this possible? If Yes, please enlighten me.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried with workflow variables with default values, 1st and 2nd points are achievable but the 3rd seems bit tricky.
[image: Sample workflow which was tried with time.. extracting time from date field]

Comment: Why is this asked again? Similar question has been put on hold here - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269453/sharepoint-2013-assign-expense-based-on-start-time-and-end-time-in-list

Comment: hey harshal, have been trying for solution. Not sure why was query put on hold. edited several times with changes.

Comment: Can you add what all you have tried?

Comment: you mean, for the solution or the query posted

Comment: You said you tried a workflow right? So can you post screenshots of the workflow you tried?

Comment: Workflow sample posted, please suggest any other solutions

Comment: I will try creating in Javascript. Create another list with columns - time slot and expense. and add lookup of timeslot field to your main list. In your main list, what type is your start time and end time?

Comment: start time and end time are single line text under calculated col.

Comment: Hi i have created time slots Vs expense list and mapped using lookup, to another list. But unable to achieve exact results. Group A, B, C, D, & E time slots, login time and logout time can be mapped directly to Group A, B or A, C slots, but how to add Slot B which is in between A, C?